# INNER JOIN COUNT on same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

here's what I am currently trying to achieve.
I have a users table which I want to join with itself. 
So I query all users with no ParentUserId and also want an additional field called ChildrenCount where I can find a count of all users with the ParentUserId = UserId.

```
SELECT p.*, COUNT(*) as ChildrenCount FROM users p
LEFT JOIN users q
on q.userid = p.ParentUserId
WHERE p.ParentUserId = 0 AND p.CategoryId = 2 ORDER BY p.userid DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

I am not getting any error but the query isn't working as I expected. I do not get the count of all related children.
Database is MYSQL.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: "I have a users table which I want to join with itself. So I query all users with no ParentUserId and also want an additional field called ChildrenCount where I can find a count of all users with the ParentUserId = UserId."
My query isn't working.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: [edit] your question and add the **exact** error message you get. Also: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: if you use a group function (like count,sum etc) you have to use "group with" with it, as i  see add a "group with" followed with all the columns from table p just before the order by clause, and check your query.

Comment: @Gar - do you mean a "group by" clause?

Comment: @Anthony Indeed, "group by"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly,
you can use a correlated query :

```
SELECT p.*, 
       (SELECT count(*) FROM users s
        WHERE s.parentUserId = p.userid) as ChildrenCount 
FROM users p
WHERE p.ParentUserId = 0 AND p.CategoryId = 2 
ORDER BY p.userid DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Aren't you in danger of 'overthinking' this one

Comment: First answer of the day, give me a break Zzz @Strawberry

Comment: I can't tell if there's sarcasm in that comment, but this looks like a spot on solution to me. Bonus points if you "overthink" this further by updating with a link to something that discusses this concept more abstractly so that we can learn when to consider similar solutions for other contexts.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. Also thank you for the link @Anthony

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need join, because you do not select anything from child table:

```
SELECT p.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` q WHERE q.userid = p.ParentUserId) as ChildrenCount
FROM `users` p
WHERE p.ParentUserId = 0 AND p.CategoryId = 2
ORDER BY p.userid DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```